# Where on Mars are there other craters or collapse features with very high depth/diameter ratio?

Tags: mars, geology, crater, collapse-feature

Figure 1 of [this article](https://www.hou.usra.edu/meetings/lpsc2016/pdf/1611.pdf) about craters and collapse features on Mars with high depth/diameter ratios shows that ratios higher than **0.2** are exceptional.

[This presentation](https://marsoweb.nas.nasa.gov/landingsites/msl/workshops/2nd_workshop/talks/Malin_N_Meridiani.pdf) of the [Program of the Second MSL Landing Site Workshop](https://marsoweb.nas.nasa.gov/landingsites/msl/workshops/2nd_workshop/program.html) about possible landing sites in [Sinus Meridiani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinus_Meridiani) shows an image of a "crater" that is 2.4 km wide and 750 meters deep ! (But judging from the elevation chart of [Mars Trek](https://trek.nasa.gov/mars/) the crater is only about 100 m deep.)

[image: Collapse feature]

Because the ratio of this feature is more than **0.3**  and it has no clear rim, it is very likely that this is not an impact crater at all.

Unusually deep fresh craters were recorded in SW Utopia and Isidis Planitia in [this article](https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1029/2005GL024462).

Are there more known features on Mars with such a very high depth/diameter ratio ?

Comment: Does this feature in the image have a name?

Comment: @BlueCoder Could not find a name at https://planetarynames.wr.usgs.gov/nomenclature/AdvancedSearch so i think you could propose a name.

Comment: The concept of a depth to diameter ratio is an interesting idea. I'm still trying to get my head around it. In a way it's an analogous of the average/overall slope angle of the wall of the "crater". This angle will largely be dictated by the properties of the wall rock (ie, by way of example, loose sand will have a shallow angle, very competent basalt will have a high angle). Generally this angle will be the angle of rest for the rock type. The other things that will affect the depth of an impact crater will be the hardness & competency of of the host rock.

Comment: Taking some rough measurements from the screen. I get a diameter of 110 mm & a wall width of 30 mm  (on the rightmost side). With a depth to diameter ratio of 0.3 the depth is 33 mm (0.3 x 110). Get the arc tan of (33/30) gives a wall angle of 47 degrees.

Comment: @Fred  Thank you for your comments. Maybe we will find a similar, much smaller feature and then we could place a transparent dome on it to keep it warm.:) (I should have added "at Fred" to my earlier comment on Sept. 12)

Comment: At first I misread this as being about holes that are actually deeper than they are wide.

Comment: You might find this interesting. [*A new global database of Mars impact craters≥1 km:2. Global crater properties and regional variationsof the simple-to-complex transition diameter*](https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1029/2011JE003967). From Fig 11, the higher d/D ratio craters seem to lie between latitudes -30 & +30.

Comment: This is certainly interesting !  Yes Fig 11, especially for fresh craters. Fig 9, for the simple, smallest craters shows some blue bins and a few of them seem to be situated near Isidis and SW Utopia Planitia.

Comment: Something else: [*Depth-diameter ratios for Martian impact craters: Implications for target properties and episodes of degradation*](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/234474962_Depth-diameter_ratios_for_Martian_impact_craters_Implications_for_target_properties_and_episodes_of_degradation) Table 1 suggests Medusae Fossae & Noachian Terraine in the Memnonia region have craters with higher values of d/D. It also suggests that region might have fine grained friable deposits. ...

Comment: ... It's also the second time I've read that the northern plains on Mars have shallower craters. Pure speculation on my part, but I'm wondering if that might also support the notion that Mars had a northern sea. The sea would absorb some of the energy from an impacting object & when that object finally hit the sea bed a shallower crater was created.

Comment: @Fred  From the last article you linked: "Craters within the martian northern plains show a tendency to become shallower with increasing latitude,........as an indication of increasing amounts of subsurface ice as the polar regions are approached.  This article is almost 30 years old and I think that explanation is now generally excepted. But yes, early Mars had probably much more water on its surface but the question is if that was still the case after 500 million years when the Late Heavy Bombardment plagued it.

Comment: @Fred  Indeed the Medusae Fossae Formation has a low density, similar to the density of hardened tuff. and is thought to be the largest source of dust with high content of sulphur and chlorine (probably perchlorates).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The d/D ratio of Martian craters vary from 0.1 to 0.4 with mean value of 0.23. The largest crater with diameter 33m has d/D ratio of 0.2 but smaller craters have higher d/D value. One crater has a surprisingly high d/D value: 0.5. A plot of d/D ratio vs diameter is drawn showing the variation in the values:

[image]

Shallower craters have d/D values of less than 0.3

[image]

a: 0.50 ; b: 0.42 ; c: 0.39 ; d: 0.42

The variation in this value depends on target material properties like varying
strength, porosity, or layering of targets; or impactor conditions such as impact velocity, impact angle, or physical state of the bolide (i.e., strength, fractured versus cohesive). The dependencies are listed below:

1. Spallation can be seen in targets with porosity up to 60%. The ratio of spall
   diameter to pit diameter is not strongly dependent on porosity and is between
   1.5 and 3. The range of the ratio is similar to those found for microcraters on
   lunar rocks and glass targets in the laboratory.
2. The depth of a crater cavity is a function of the density ratio of the projectile
   and target. However, it is also dependent on the impact velocity and porosity of
   the target.
3. The normalized diameters of craters on porous targets tends to decrease with
   increasing target porosity. An empirical scaling law derived for porous
   sedimentary rocks based on conventional scaling laws is shown to be a reference for craters on brittle
   targets, including porous targets of various porosities.
4. **The depth-to-diameter ratio of the crater cavity is roughly 0.5 for tuff and
   gypsum, with porosities of about 43% and 50%, respectively. On the other hand,
   the ratio is about 0.2 for sandstones and cement mortar,** although the porosity
   of cement mortar is about 40% and similar to that of tuff. No strong velocity
   dependence is evident in the depth-to-diameter ratio, although the ratio changes
   with impact velocity for microcraters produced on non-porous glass.
5. Crater shape is roughly a trigonal pyramid for craters with a depth-to-diameter
   ratio of less than 0.3

References:

1. Daubar, I. J., C. Atwood-Stone, S. Byrne, A. S. McEwen, and P. S. Russell (2014),
   The morphology of small fresh craters on Mars and the Moon, J. Geophys. Res.
   Planets, 119, 2620–2639, doi:[10.1002/2014JE004671](https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/2014JE004671).
2. Impact cratering on porous targets in the strength regime by Akiko M. Nakamura ([PDF](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1709/1709.05478.pdf))

Answer (score 0):

[image: Pit crater]
Credits: NASA/JPL-Caltech/University of Arizona

This image is a screenshot of the color version of [HiRISE's ESP_043222_2035](https://uahirise.org/ESP_043222_2035).
From [Pit Crater near Elysium Mons](https://uahirise.org/ESP_043222_2035):

> This image was taken of an area on the lower southeastern flank of the volcano Elysium Mons. In the center is a small, dark pristine-appearing pit approximately 130 meters in diameter, which is clearly visible among the numerous small impact craters that are heavily covered by dust and sediment.

> Garden variety craters are excavated by impacts and are characterized by raised rims, sloped walls and surrounded by ejecta blankets, but pit craters are simply sink holes in the ground with near vertical walls and floors that are only visible when the sun is high in the sky. They are deep holes that may lead to underground caves in volcanic terrain.

When the image was taken the Sun was about 51⁰ above the horizon, and we can see that the shadow of the crater rim then reached about the center of the floor.
So the **depth** of the crater floor center then is: tan 51⁰ x 65 m. = **~ 80 m.**, and the **d/D ratio**: **~ 0.6**.